# Client responsibility for conduct of contractor?

Tags: contracts

I sometimes run across insinuations that contracting provides a measure of insulation from accountability or lack of expertise/capacity, e.g., for companies or government offices that are subject to many regulations, militaries in expeditionary missions, property managers running large building complexes.

**In general, if the client is supposed to uphold certain obligations in providing their services, and they contract out some of their responsibilities, are they responsible for ensuring that the contractors uphold those obligations on their behalf?**  These obligations can take many forms, e.g., environmental obligations, supporting domestic economy, ethical rules (applying to militaries, governments, and corporations), safety, acceptable or reasonable quality and timeliness of work, etc.

Having just done a quick jaunt through the web, it seems that certain aspects can get quite complicated especially when outsourcing abroad, and/or when a home-based client performs operations abroad but outsources some work to home-based organizations with a presence abroad.  I wonder if the question can be simplified by focusing on the most basic concept of a contract.  Is there be some fundamental expectation that a client is not absolved of obligations by the mere act of outsourcing their responsibilities?  Would this also apply if a contractor sub-contracts?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this seems to be either company specific OR a question about contract law - which is within the domain of SE:Law

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In general, if the client is supposed to uphold certain obligations in
>   providing their services, and they contract out some of their
>   responsibilities, are they responsible for ensuring that the
>   contractors uphold those obligations on their behalf?

The client has responsibilities to their stakeholders (customers, government offices, etc). Those responsibilities cannot be shirked by passing on some of the work to sub-contractors.

The client owns the responsibility. How they assure their responsibilities are met varies (auditing, direct oversight, financial penalties, etc.), but they are still ultimately responsible.

Comment: I think the term "stakeholders" is pivotal. The government may farm out work to a company that violates some government obligations to the environment. I presume that the contractors is only liable to the extent that these obligations are captured in the contract (as suggested in another answer) and the government is responsible for the rest. The stakeholder might be the rest of the world, the country, or some oversight body. When militaries contract private security firms to help abroad, stakeholders can conceivably extend to those being policed or assessed for hostility/friendliness.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR; Yes.

Part of contracting with the government is that a contract company agrees that its consultants will abide by all the rules, regulations, and Laws regarding their work for the government.  There are provisions for damages and remuneration based on bad conduct by the contractors.

This is part of why some government contracts can be thousands of pages long for seemingly simple tasks.  And if you perform poorly enough [the company can be blacklisted from government work](https://www.jacksonlewis.com/resources-publication/blacklisting-rules-government-contractors-proposed-federal-agencies-under-executive-order).

Comment: There may be provisions for the government to pursue, but if the citizens being serviced encounter issues, they likely have to seek redress through the government rather than the contractor (unless a direct mechanism is provided for in the contract). I can see how it can get messy, with things falling between the cracks.

Comment: @user2153235 and after a crack is found another 50 pages will be added to the next contract to fill in that crack...

Answer (score 1):

2 excellent answers already, so from another angle.

Pragmatically it does provide some insulation both for the department and more importantly for the individuals involved because it gives them more leeway for excuses when things go South and therefore makes the individual less accountable (in practice, not theory).

I have seen whole govt careers built on series of failed projects for which the people involved were not held accountable and steadily rose to high positions. It's par for the course in the third World but it also happens everywhere else.

Comment: Ah yes.  The practical reality aspect.  On the challenges of accountability, I also see that it is sometimes hard to identify success or failure when an organization is meeting needs that are not defined by the market.